# .replaceAll(/\. /g, '.\n \n') not working in chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, line-breaks

I am building a real time speech to text app with React and I am trying to do line breaks after a sentence ends. Currently, I am trying to achieve this with regex and what I have so far is working in most browsers but not Chrome. Chrome is one of the most popular browsers so this is a problem for me...

This is the regex that I am using right now:

```js
.replaceAll(/\. /g, '.\n \n')
```

what this is doing is replacing any period(.) with a period(.) and two line breaks (\n) for spacing purposes. When I run my app in google chrome it does not respect the line breaks and just creates one long paragraph when transcribing my speech to text, however, it works perfectly in Microsoft Edge, just as I intended.

Has anyone had an issue with regex in Google Chrome? am I missing something? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It might be a CSS problem. Try giving your element style [`white-space: pre-line;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: Thank you Hao Wu, currently I do have this for my element style and it still seems to not work. However, before I added `white-space: pre-line;` it was not working in any browsers. It still seems to be a Google Chrome problem. Sorry this is my first time using stack overflow and I dont know how to markdown my code snippets

Comment: It does sound weird. It would be very helpful for if you can share your code or create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here.

Comment: this is my CSS:

`.transcript {
  white-space: pre-line;
}`

This is the code I'm trying to use to replace (.) with line breaks:

`const transcriptBreak = transcript.replaceAll(/\. /g, '.\n \n')`

Comment: You can edit your question and elaborate your problem, and also show the relevant code of the part how you manipulate the DOM.